# Discord.js Autocomplete 'Loading Options Failed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of creating a discord bot using discord.js v14 and have encountered a problem with the autocomplete feature. I followed the discord.js [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/autocomplete.html) on the command exactly, and no error shows up, but when I try to use the command, it shows 'Loading Options Failed':

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('testing')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('option')
                .setDescription('The option to select')
                .setRequired(true)
                .setAutocomplete(true)),
    async autocomplete(interaction) {
        const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
        const choices = ['Apples' , 'Oranges' , 'Bananas' , 'Grapes' , 'Watermelons'];
        const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedValue));
        await interaction.respond(
            filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
        );
    },
};
```

Here is my index.js file if it is needed:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
const { token, clientId, guildId } = require('./config.json');
let slashcmdExec = require("./deploy-slashcmds.js")
slashcmdExec.deployCommands()

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    
   client.user.setPresence({
  activities: [{ name: `over Everything...`, type: ActivityType.Watching }],
  status: 'idle',
});
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return console.log("Command was not found");

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }

});

client.login(token);
```

I saw a similar post that said to remove `if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;` and so I did, but the error still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't handle autocomplete inside your `InteractionCreate` handler. Your current code only works with commands.

You can check if the `interaction` is an autocomplete interaction with [`isAutcocomplete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=isAutocomplete). If it is, you can run the `autocomplete()` method of your exported object.

Now that you handle autocomplete, you can add another if statement that checks if the interaction is a command. You can use [`isChatInputCommand()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction?scrollTo=isChatInputCommand) for this.

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return console.log('Command was not found');

    if (!command.autocomplete)
      return console.error(
        `No autocomplete handler was found for the ${interaction.commandName} command.`,
      );

    try {
      await command.autocomplete(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return console.log('Command was not found');

    try {
      await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      await interaction.reply({
        content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }
  }
});
```